# JuMPeR issue Julia

Tags: julia

Issue using JuMPeR because of Grisu dependancy. I followed examples to avoid issue to no help.

I tried

```
using Pkg
Pkg.add("JuMPeR")

Pkg.add("Grisu")

if isdefined(Base, :Grisu)
    import Base.Grisu
else
    import Grisu
end

using JuMP
using GLPK

println("done")
```

but I still get:

```
LoadError: UndefVarError: `Grisu` not defined
Stacktrace:
```